# Delete next row after every count/list of day; in R

Tags: r, date, count, delete-row

I am finding it difficult to wrap my head around this:
In the dataframe below I want to delete the next row after every count/list of, say, Thursday, same for Friday and so on. I would prefer not using a loop since the data is big.

```
mydata<- read.table(header=TRUE, text=" 

    Date     AAPL.ret  Weekday Thursday
```

1 2001-01-04  0.000000000 Thursday        1
2 2001-01-04  0.000000000 Thursday        1
3 2001-01-04 -0.025317808 Thursday        1
4 2001-01-04  0.014545711 Thursday        1
5 2001-01-04  0.007194276 Thursday        1
6 2001-01-04 -0.007194276 Thursday        1
7 2001-01-05 -0.0278569545   Friday       0
8 2001-01-05  0.0056338177   Friday       0
9 2001-01-05  0.0037383221   Friday       0
10 2001-01-05  0.0000000000  Friday       0
11 2002-02-25  3.511856e-03  Monday       0
12 2002-02-25 -3.511856e-03  Monday       0
13 2002-02-25 -4.398505e-04  Monday       0
14 2002-02-25 -2.643173e-03  Monday       0
15 2002-02-25  4.401416e-03  Monday       0
16 2002-02-26  9.189066e-03  Tuesday      0
17 2002-02-26 -8.243166e-04  Tuesday      0
18 2002-02-26  9.533751e-03  Tuesday      0
19 2002-02-26  4.527688e-03  Tuesday      0
20 2002-02-26  4.105933e-04  Tuesday      0
.............
100 2002-03-01  8.717651e-03  Friday      0
101 2002-03-01  1.990115e-02  Friday      0
102 2002-03-01 -1.344387e-03  Friday      0
103 2002-03-01 -1.445373e-02  Friday      0
    ")
The output I need should be like this:

```
    Date     AAPL.ret  Weekday Thursday
```

1 2001-01-04  0.000000000 Thursday        1
2 2001-01-04  0.000000000 Thursday        1
3 2001-01-04 -0.025317808 Thursday        1
4 2001-01-04  0.014545711 Thursday        1
5 2001-01-04  0.007194276 Thursday        1
6 2001-01-04 -0.007194276 Thursday        1
7 2001-01-05  0.0056338177   Friday       0
8 2001-01-05  0.0037383221   Friday       0
9 2001-01-05  0.0000000000   Friday       0
11 2002-02-25 -3.511856e-03  Monday       0
12 2002-02-25 -4.398505e-04  Monday       0
13 2002-02-25 -2.643173e-03  Monday       0
14 2002-02-25  4.401416e-03  Monday       0
15 2002-02-26 -8.243166e-04  Tuesday      0
16 2002-02-26  9.533751e-03  Tuesday      0
17 2002-02-26  4.527688e-03  Tuesday      0
18 2002-02-26  4.105933e-04  Tuesday      0
.............
100 2002-03-01  1.990115e-02  Friday      0
101 2002-03-01 -1.344387e-03  Friday      0
102 2002-03-01 -1.445373e-02  Friday      0

Thank you in advance. Sorry if I have wrongfully asked the question. This is my first time of asking a question here; I have tried to follow the rules as best as I can; especially how the table should appear.

The codes I have tried, I believe, are really far from the answer I desire. Just counting and subsetting; below.
table(ret.df$Weekday=="Thursday")
r1<-ret.df[!(ret.df$Weekday=="Thursday"),]

I hope my question less vague now.

A follow up from the previous answer:

## removing rows based on condition in ret_1ON

```
ret_1ON<- ret.df[duplicated(ret.df$Date)|1:nrow(ret.df)==1,]
```

dim(ret_1ON)

[1] 98734     4

```
head(ret_1ON)

    Date     AAPL.ret  Weekday Thursday
```

1 2001-01-04  0.000000000 Thursday        1
2 2001-01-04  0.000000000 Thursday        1
3 2001-01-04 -0.025317808 Thursday        1
4 2001-01-04  0.014545711 Thursday        1
5 2001-01-04  0.007194276 Thursday        1
6 2001-01-04 -0.007194276 Thursday        1

```
tail(ret_1ON)
        Date      AAPL.ret  Weekday Thursday
```

99994 2006-01-19  0.0013771520 Thursday        1
99995 2006-01-19 -0.0007321584 Thursday        1
99996 2006-01-19 -0.0029026141 Thursday        1
99997 2006-01-19 -0.0002511616 Thursday        1
99998 2006-01-19  0.0011297309 Thursday        1
99999 2006-01-19 -0.0002509410 Thursday        1

I'm wandering why the last item in tail is not 98734 but rather 99999?

```
dim(ret.df)
```

[1] 99999     4
which means the condition was effected, though.

Comment: What is your desired output from this data? Is it just "remove row 79"?

Comment: @r2evans removing row 79 is only the first thing I need, then the same process repeats for all the days in the data. I have only shown a part of the data.

Comment: Yes, so in *this* data, the only difference is row 79, right? (You don't have to show this much data to accomplish the question, btw. You might grab 5-8 rows from each day, showing multiple days, so that the answers you receive may be more flexible/correct.)

Comment: Are you intending to remove the first row of each day? Your description is a little vague. Could you please modify your data so that 95% of it isn't the same day? Also, please indicate your desired output and/or which rows (numerically) you think should be removed. Lastly, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: @r2evans Thank you. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, .SD[(seq_len(.N) != 1)], Date]
```

if we wanted to keep the first row of the dataset

```
setDT(mydata)[, .SD[(seq_len(.N) != 1)|seq_len(.N)==.I[1]], Date]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
      group_by(Date) %>%
      filter(row_number() != 1)
```

---

Or using `base R`, if the 'Date' column is `order`ed

```
mydata[duplicated(mydata$Date),]
```

or with including the first row

```
mydata[duplicated(mydata$Date)|1:nrow(mydata)==1,]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code perfectly gives me what I need.